# What is the total supply of IOTA?

Tags: economics

In Bitcoin the total supply is capped at 21 million BTC. In Ethereum things are slightly looser. (I don't know what their total supply will be.)

What's the case for IOTA? Is there a cap, and if so, what is the amount?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The exact total supply of IOTA is 2,779,530,283,277,761 units. This value is optimized for ternary computation and can be expressed as 2.779 x 10<sup>15</sup>. The total supply is based on the 33 digit ternary number 111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111,111.

Comment: Can you please explain how 2.779 x 10^15 is related to SI units?

Comment: This was meant as a reference to the Système international d’unités, working with decimal power. Please ignore if too confusing.

Comment: But I can not see any SI unit here. How does SI correlate with scientific notation?

Comment: I was under the belief that this term is used speaking of decimal power in general. I corrected it.

Comment: No problem, I was just asking to be sure I am not missing something.

Answer (score 15):

IOTA is a non-inflationary currency in that there are a fixed number of tokens in circulation and the protocol doesn't algorithmically create additional supply.

This number is currently ((3<sup>33</sup>)-1)/2 or 2,779,530,283,277,761 iota -- but it ***can* be changed when necessary**. This has [happened in the past](https://forum.iota.org/t/iota-tech-update/264) and involved all existing balances to inflate along with it.

Comment: I think we should use the upvote button to show our appreciation for an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The total amount of IOTAs circulating supplies are 2.779.530.283 MIOTA as you can see on [CoinMarketCap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/iota/)

IOTA can't be mined that means they won't get more.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Don't forget that when you buy from an exchange the default unit is MIOTA (1 million IOTA)

PS: Just for comparison, the total amount of Bitcoin is 21 million but if you take the smallest subdivision (Satoshi) in order to compare with Iota the smallest subdivision of IOTA it goes like this.

**2,100,000,000,000,000 Satoshi  --  2,779,530,283,277,761 Iota**

As you can see the supply of IOTA and BTC is about the same. If you want to compare prices you can use the following measure.

**1 Bitcoin is equivalent to ~132 MIOTA**

*The amount of IOTA is fixed, all in the hands of people and it's not mineable.*

Comment: Posting exchange rates seems very unhelpful due to the volatility of both currencies.

Comment: I didn't put exchange rates. I just put the equivalent iota to bitcoin rate. In case someone wants to compare the day's price and see this info.

Comment: How does that rate differ from an exchange rate? Isn't that exactly the Bitcoin MIOTA exchange rate?

Comment: 1 Bitcoin is not = to 132Miota. That just the proportion compared to the total supply for each coin. It has nothing to do with the value of any of the 2 coins.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense. It would be great if you could clarify that in your answer via [edit].

Answer (score -2):

The maximum supply for IOTA is 2,779,530,283 MIOTA

Comment: Answers without references are usually discouraged. Please [edit] the answer to improve it.