# What happens with microtransactions if 1 IOTA = 1$

Tags: microtransaction

I know it ist still far to go, but in the very long future when 1 IOTA is maybe worth 1$ how can we do microtransactions? Is there a possibility to split 1 the total amounts of IOTAs even more? I think at that time there will be no $ anymore, but still the question remains ;-)

Comment: Why would that have any impact? There are many currencies out there which have enormously different scaling than the US dollar. What concerns do you have? There's no reason why the IOTA-dollar exchange rate should be of any concern for microtransactions posed in your question. (And I don't think there is any.) Currently this is just a call for speculation which is why I've voted to close this for being primarily opinion based.

Comment: The question is how to make microtransactions if the smalest amount of IOTA is worth 1$. The currency doesnt matter. It is just to explain the question...

Comment: I meant you want to pay 0.02$ but you cannot because 1 IOTA is worth 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be no Problem. Like pointed out [in this answer](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/487/665), the devs will add smaller denominations and scale everyones IOTA accordingly to the new ones. So everyone will keep the same Value as before, but will have for example 10GIOTA instead of 10MIOTA