# The smallest unit in IOTA is 1 Iota. Is it divisable? Can a fraction of an IOTA be used?

Tags: token

Can a fraction of an IOTA be used? Currently 1 Iota is only worth 2.5 Millionths of a dollar. Imagining IOTA token being used for microscopic transactions can an IOTA be divided?

Comment: This topic has been already discussed. See for example [this](https://iota.stackexchange.com/a/487/212)  answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, 1 IOTA (not MIOTA) is the smallest usable unit and it is not divisible.

However, in the (admittedly) unrealistic case that the value of 1 IOTA increases too much be useful for micro transactions, it is possible to effectively add extra decimal places by artificially increasing the overall supply (see e.g. [this link](https://forum.iota.org/t/iota-tech-update/264) for an instance when this happened).