# How to find earliest confirming (referencing) milestone for the confirmed transaction?

Tags: confirmation, milestones, coordinator

This question is about a) iterating milestones starting from the latest and b) most efficient way to find if it references the transaction. Note, that a milestone not necessary refers to previous milestone, i.e. milestones not always form a chain afaik. (Edit: another milestone -> previous milestone)

Comment: A milestone **has to**  refer to the previous milestone, at least indirectly. ([How exactly are transactions verified and confirmed in IOTA](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/1577/10))

Comment: I remember one accident when it wasn't referring to the **previous** and hot discussion on discord afterwords. Hercules wasn't able to sync then. It turned out that normally yes, but not always and it was confirmed by IF.

Comment: To find milestones, you can search for Coo address. Milestones always have milestone number in the tag, so you can easily find a particular one. Hard part is to verify signature in case there are any fake milestones. To check whether a milestone confirmed a transaction, you can use `checkInclusionState` API.

Comment: thank you. I guess you mean `getInclusionStates`. 
Is coo address always `KPWCHICGJZXKE9GSUDXZYUAPLHAKAHYHDXNPHENTERYMMBQOPSQIDENXKLKCEYCPVTZQLEEJVYJZV9BWU` ?